# pdf-lib - Ensure text remains on page (using wrapping and size reduction)

Tags: typescript

I am using pdf-lib to generate some PDF documents dynamically.

The text content I am adding can vary in length.

Is there a way to set a bounding box (or something similar) to ensure my text fits within this area?  As an example below I want to ensure that my text both wraps and reduces in size as needed to fit in a particular area.

```
populatePage(pdfPage: PDFPage, pdfFont: PDFFont): void {

const { width, height } = pdfPage.getSize();

const text = 'This is a really long bit of text and I want it to remain on the page and resize as needed and not get cut off';

pdfPage.drawText(text, {
  x: width / 2 - (text.length * 10),
  y: height - 200,
  size: 40,
  font: pdfFont,
  color: rgb(0.95, 0.1, 0.1)
});
```

}

Answer (score 5):

drawText accepts a maxWidth, when this width is exceeded it will wrap your text!
https://pdf-lib.js.org/docs/api/interfaces/pdfpagedrawtextoptions

Comment: it does not work with links

Answer (score 2):

Use maxWidth with wordBreaks. i.e

```
const text = 'This is a really long bit of text and I want it to remain on the page and resize as needed and not get cut off';

pdfPage.drawText(text, {
  x: width / 2 - (text.length * 10),
  y: height - 200,
  size: 40,
  font: pdfFont,
  color: rgb(0.95, 0.1, 0.1),
  maxWidth: 500, wordBreaks: [" "]
});
```